# WSS "Cannot connect to the configuration database"

Tags: windows-server-2003, sharepoint, wss-3.0, wss

I have 64-bit WSS 3.0 installed on a 64-bit Windows 2003 Server. After installing WSS 3.0 I switched IIS to run in 32-bit emulation mode as we have some applications that require this.

I'm getting a "Cannot connect to the configuration database" trying to get to the Central Admin page and wondered if:

a. The setup I have won't work and I'm wasting my time trying to figure this out.

or

b. If anyone has any suggestions for resolving the database connection issue?

The identity of the app pool that WSS runs under has all the required permissions in SQL so far as I can tell.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Tim: can you clarify - did the WSS site work before switching to 32-bit emulation mode?

Comment: @MattB, yeah WSS site works fine when IIS is in 64-bit mode and we remove an ISAPI filter that requires 32-bit emulation mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, SharePoint cannot run in 32-bit emulation mode on a 64-bit server. Here is the Microsoft documentation to back that up:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288751.aspx

Comment: Yeah, this is what I suspected, just hoped I was wrong! Decided to put WSS on a different server for now until we can remove the need to run IIS in 32-bit mode. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

64 and 32 bit SQL Client have different configuration parameters.  My guess is the 32 bit settings are not configured properly.

To modify these settings open SQL Server Configuration Manager (it is an MMC snap-in so you can find it in the mmc.exe Add/Remove Snap-In screen).  You want to make sure that the configuration for SQL Native Client Configuration (32bit) matches the configuration for SQL Native Client Configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not really an expert in this area so can I edit the 32-bit settings for the SQL Client and if so where can I find these settings?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks JD, the settings are the same. Think MattB is right that we can't run WSS in 32-bit emulation mode - will just have to put this on a different server. Thanks for your help.